# Shrink viewing cell of R plots in jupyter

Tags: r, plot, jupyter

I am running R in jupyter, but I am running across some issues with plotting. Specifically whenever I plot the returned plotting window takes up the entire screen. I tried changing the dimension of the plot in R with `par(pin=c(1,1))` etc... and it shrunk the actual image of the plot, but the cell width the images is in still takes up the entire screen. I can zoom out in my browser, but then I can't see my lines of code.

Code:

```
x <- runif(100)  
hist(x)
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this would be appreciated. Thanks.

P.S. I would post an image, but I just created this account and need at least 10 rep points to post images

Answer:

I was able to change the options  with the code below so my plots looked a little bit more reasonable

```
options(repr.plot.height=3)
options(repr.plot.width=3)
```

Comment: Can you provide some of the code you wrote so far?

Comment: x <- runif(100) ; hist(x)

Comment: `options(repr.plot.res = 60)` will also shrink down the plot (default 120).  Separate note, thanks for posting this question.  Didn't know R in Jupyter was a thing before this.

Comment: This is my question as well.